# Hiding rows in a table that are hidden in another table on a separate sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, match, filtering

I am working on, and need help with, a program that will hide rows in a table, when the line with a matching serial number is hidden on a separate table.

In one table I have a list of businesses labelled with serial numbers from 00001 to 01000, and on a separate table on a separate sheet I have over 1000 contacts for different businesses, but for some I may have more than one contact (Ex. Bus 00002 has 5 contacts while bus 00161 has only 2 contacts). Basically I want the program to find any hidden businesses lines in Table/Sheet 1 and hide any contacts on table2/sheet 2 with matching serial numbers.

This is what I currently have and it had worked a few times at first but would only hide the first contacts for each "business" that was hidden. But recently it has stopped working completely. I'm not a professional programmer so any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
Sub Testnumber14()

    Dim table1 As ListObject
    Set table1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Bus_List")
    
    Dim table2 As ListObject
    Set table2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("Contact_List")
    
    Dim myRow As Range
    Dim busRow As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    For Each myRow In table2.DataBodyRange.Rows

    If Application.Match(myRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, table1.Range.Columns(1), 0) Then
        
        For Each busRow In table1.DataBodyRange.Rows
            
                If table1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            
                    table2.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         
                Else
                    table2.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    
                End If
            Next busRow
        End If
    Next myRow
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary to store all the hidden rows, then apply that to the second table:

```vb
Sub Testnumber14()

    Dim table1 As ListObject, table2 As ListObject
    Dim dict As Object, c As Range
    
    Set table1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Bus_List")
    Set table2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("Contact_List")
   
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    For Each c In table1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells
        If c.EntireRow.Hidden Then dict(c.Value) = True
    Next c
    
    For Each c In table2.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = dict.exists(c.Value)
    Next c
    
End Sub
```